# How to use basic regular expressions within gulp.src?

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp, glob

I'm trying to select two files with `gulp.src`: `highcharts.js` and `highcharts.src.js`.

Of course I know I could add explicitly these two with an array expression, but for learning purposes I'm trying to write a single expression for them.

I've read that one can use simple regular expression syntax but it's not clear how.

I tried

```
gulp.src("highcharts(\.src)?\.js")
```

but it didn't match any files.

Comment: Try `gulp.src("highcharts.{src.js,js}")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you that actually works, even the simplified (but uglier) `gulp.src("highcharts{.src,}.js")` but I still wonder then how we can use actual regular expression syntax. Or maybe we can't, and I misunderstood something?

Comment: gulp.src only support glob, or write custom function with glob + regex and pass list of files to gulp.src

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gulp uses [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) which doesn't support the regular expressions you're normally used to. It uses special globbing patterns that are optimized to matching files.

Your example could be written as:

```
gulp.src('highcharts?(.src).js')
```

Check out the [glob primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) for more examples of what's possible with `glob`.

Comment: Ah that's a good resource finally, thank you for the link. Thank you for the concrete solution too.