# How to get Gulp src to see extension of file with multiple dots in name?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a number of jpg/png files with filenames like this:

- 2019.03.12_camera.large.jpg
- 2019.03.16_camera.medium.png
- 2019.03.19_camera.large.jpg

I am attempting to run a function that gets images and compresses them. However Gulp src seems to only see the first dot, so ignores the file.

I am using the following code:

```
return src(`./${folderName}/**/**.!(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)`, {
    base: `./${folderName}/`,
    dot: true,
}).pipe(dest('./output/dirty/'))
```

There seems to be no setting to change this, and my regex is pretty poor. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305530/175121

Comment: Try this: `*.?(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg), {` with no need for the `dot` option.  Let me know if that works.  Your `!` is a negation, so it is excluding those files!

Comment: Nice one Mark, that seems to have done the trick!